# Zip sent via email is invalid on first attempt

Tags: python, email, python-3.x, mime-types, mime

I try to create a zip archive containing all files from a specific directory(and subdirectories) and send it via mail:

```
#Create archive containing all files from directory "reports/"
zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('reports.zip', 'w')
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('reports/'):
for file in files:
    zipf.write(os.path.join(root, file))

#Create email
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg["From"] = emailfrom
msg["To"] = emailto
msg["Subject"] = "Monatliche Reports - Verrechnung an Kunden"

#Attach report.zip to email
fp = open(fileToSend, "rb")
attachment = MIMEBase('application', 'zip')
attachment.set_payload(fp.read())
fp.close()
encoders.encode_base64(attachment)
attachment.add_header("Content-Disposition", "attachment",
filename=fileToSend)
msg.attach(attachment)

#Send email via localhost smtp-server
server = smtplib.SMTP("localhost")
server.sendmail(emailfrom, emailto, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

The script seems to work. I recive the mail including the attached zip archive containing all the files. When the script is executed there are 2 possible situations:

Case 1: there is already a zip archive before executing the script, named report.zip (old one from the last run)

Case 2: there is no zip archive before executing the script.

In case 1 everything works fine. The old one is replaced with the newly generated and will then be sent via email.

**In case 2 the report.zip is generated and sent via email, but it is invalid. If I try to open it on Windows with 7zip(or the windows onboard tools) it just say "the archive is invalid". I found out that only the report.zip sent via email is broken. If I send the report.zip generated in Case 2 by hand via email I can unzip it and use the files.**

I'm a python newbie and to be honest it was hard enough to get to the point where I am at the moment, but solving this problem headaches me. Can anyone explain me what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close the zip file after adding the files to ensure the archive is complete.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.close

better yet use a `with` statement :

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('reports.zip', 'w') as zipf: 
   for root, dirs, files in os.walk('reports/'):
      for file in files:
         zipf.write(os.path.join(root, file))
```

---

*Details* As I understand them.

**1st run**:

- zipfile creates a file descriptor (in memory placeholder) and a package manifest (files to add)
- zipfile.write() compresses files into the file descriptor and adds the file to the manifest
- msg.attach() the file hasn't flushed so there is nothing at location still in memory.
- --End script file descriptor clean up flushes file descriptor to disk. ( reports.zip exists but is incomplete/invalid )

**2nd run**:

- zipfile creates a fd and manifest
- zipfile.write() compresses files to the fd and adds the file to the manifest
- msg.attach() the file had flushed last time but is still incomplete **Attaches invalid file**.

Comment: Thx this does resolve the problem, but I'm still confused that it worked on a 2nd attempt with my code. Why should the archive be closed on 2nd run while it remains open on the first attempt ?

Comment: because when the script finishes the interpreter will close the file. and on the second attempt it would get the (partial) file. The zipfile was still open and ready for more files at the end of the first pass, and would be an incomplete package.

Comment: So it is an incomplete package at first attempt because of the fact that the file was still open when the script finished executing ? I can't see the difference to attempt 2. There happens exactly the same, the File is also open at the time when the script finishes.
Thank you so much for your explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import yagmail
me = 'me@gmail.com'
yag = yagmail.SMTP(emailfrom, 'mypassword') 
yag.send(emailto,  "Monatliche Reports - Verrechnung an Kunden", 'reports.zip')
```

You will probably have to install yagmail with `pip install yagmail`

Disclaimer: I'm the developer of [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail), a package that tries to make it easy to send emails (with or without attachments).

Comment: Looks interesting, I will give it a try. Thx for your hint